# Is there a way to Zoom a Rich Textbox's contents in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I am trying to zoom (resize) the contents of a rich text box in VB6 so that all the content is visible. (I zoom out until the scroll bars disapear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you might be able to simulate it by the following.

- create a large form and position if offscreen somewhere
- put your RichEdit (or a copy of it) onto this form
- size the RichEdit so that it can hold everything without scrollbars
- create a memory dc (`CreateDC`) and select a bitmap into it that's large enough to hold the contents of your RichEdit (`CreateDIBSection`)
- send the offscreen RichEdit a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message containing the memory DC
- `StretchBlt` from the Memory DC to the screen where you want your zoomed view.

  (whew!)